# Stripped ending utf8 chars if set as caps

Tags: xetex

I am using xelatex and while formatting by `\caps` (packages `soul`, `soulutf8`, `polyglossia`), the ending utf8 signs get stripped ("gītā" gets "gīt", see image below).  Did anybody notice this issue and could give some help please?

The document can be simplified as follows:

```
% xelatex, texlive 2013
\documentclass[]{scrbook}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{soul,soulutf8}
\begin{document}

\caps{gītā}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update:**

Thanks to the kind help, I could redefine the document as follows and understand the matter better:

```
% xelatex, texlive 2013
\documentclass[]{scrbook}
\usepackage{polyglossia}  % calls fontspec
\setmainfont
[Ligatures=TeX,
SmallCapsFeatures={LetterSpace=3.0},  % \textsc{} rather than \caps{} from "soul"
Numbers=OldStyle,
]
{TeX Gyre Pagella}  % could be any unicode font which supports small capitals
\begin{document}

\textsc{gītā}

\end{document}
```

I would also appreciate if somebody could explain shortly the main difference between \textsc{} from "fontspec" with letter spacing, \caps{} from "soul" and a feature if provided by "microtype".

Comment: Why not use a font which supports this in conjunction with `fontspec` rather than trying to use something like `soul`? That is, you are using xelatex in any case, so why not use the features that enables you to access?

Comment: Avoid `xltxtra`, unless you *really* need its features (I bet you don't). Load just `fontspec`.

Answer (score 7):

Package `soul` checks the character tokens with the font `\SOUL@tt`. This is defined in LaTeX as:

\newfont\SOUL@tt{ectt1000}

However, you are using a Unicode enabled TeX engine. There many characters are not available in font `ectt1000`. The `.log` file contains the messages:

```
Missing character: There is no ī in font ectt1000!
Missing character: There is no ā in font ectt1000!
```

The workaround is to redefine `\SOUL@tt` to use a better font:

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{soul}

\makeatletter
\sbox0{\ttfamily\global\let\SOUL@tt\ttfamily} 
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \caps{gītā}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remark:**

- Package `soulutf8` is intended to support UTF-8 for 8-bit TeX engines, where a Unicode character consists of several TeX chars/tokens with character codes < 256, encoded as UTF-8. This requires changes of the `soul` parser.

  However, XeTeX and LuaTeX support Unicode characters as single tokens/big chars. Thus the parser of `soul` does not need to be changed and `soulutf8` is not needed and should not be used.

Comment: What is the difference between what `soul` does here and what is offered by `fontspec`'s use of the different capitalisation/small-capitalisation/etc. features (for fonts which support those features)? (And maybe with `microtype`.)

Comment: [This](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250269/how-to-use-inter-letter-space-for-justified-alignment) problem is related. I tried to apply your solution from here, but it doesn't quite work for my case.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need `soul` for this, as letter spacing can be defined directly through `fontspec`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[
  Ligatures=TeX,
  SmallCapsFont=Latin Modern Roman Caps,
  SmallCapsFeatures={LetterSpace=2.5},
]{Latin Modern Roman}

\begin{document}
\textsc{gītā}

\scriptsize\MakeUppercase{gītā} % for checking

\end{document}
```

[image]