# Problems with pdfcomments and Unicode characters in XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, unicode, highlighting, pdfcomment

I'm trying to use the `pdfcomment` package in XeLaTeX. I can't seem to be able to use Unicode characters such as Czech `ň` or `ě` properly in `\pdfmarkupcomment`. Usually any such trailing characters of the comment disappear. Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{czech}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\hypersetup{unicode}
\begin{document}
Běžně. Běžně.

\pdfmarkupcomment{Běžně}{}. Běžně. % This would be typeset as "Běžn. Běžně" leaving out "ě"
\end{document}
```

The pdfcomment package documentation says:

> Internally, the argument ⟨comment⟩ needs to be converted to PDFDocEncoding/PDFUnicode.

and then it just says `\hypersetup{unicode}` in a footnote to this, which is what I put in my LaTeX document, but it does not seem to solve the problem. (I have no idea what "needs to be converted to PDFDocEncoding/PDFUnicode" means.)

Alternatively, if there is a different way to highlight arbitrary parts of text (i.e. without creating a box around it), that would work OK with Unicode, I will be happy to use it.

Comment: Note that `\pdfmarkupcomment` wants *two* mandatory arguments. The problem seems to be a bug in `soulpos`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, this was the cause of the immediately following character disappearing. I have edited the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hinted by egreg in comment, I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157435/stripped-ending-utf8-chars-if-set-as-caps).

It seems like `soul` tries analysising your string by typeseting a prototype in font `\SOUL@tt`. If the last few characters are missed in that font, `soul` would found that it just built a zero-width box. It then think that the current string is finished and stop working.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,pdfcomment}
\begin{document}

\ulposdef{\uline}{\rule[-.8ex]{\ulwidth}{.5pt}}

\uline{Běžně}
\pdfmarkupcomment{Běžně}{}. Běžně. % This would be typeset as "Běžn. Běžně" leaving out "ě"
%leaving out "ě"

\makeatletter
\let\SOUL@tt\ttfamily
\makeatother

\uline{Běžně}
\pdfmarkupcomment{Běžně}{}. Běžně. % This would be typeset as "Běžn. Běžně" leaving out "ě"
%leaving out "ě"

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, yes! I forgot about this one! Probably `soul` should check for `fontspec` and then do that assignment itself.