# How to use inter letter space for justified alignment?

Tags: soul, letterspacing

I have a long sanskrit compound taking up almost a line, but leaving a small space at the right margin empty, too small for the first syllable of the next word, thus breaking the justified alignment. See example in footnote 1. Taking inspiration from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50508/fully-stretch-text-horizontally-on-page) I did some experiments with the `soul` package, with an almost satisfying result, see footnote 2, but the word's last letter disappeared.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setlength{\footmarkwidth}{\leftmargin}
\setlength{\footmarksep}{0em}
\footmarkstyle{#1\hfill}

\sodef\spaceout{}{0em plus 1fil}{0em plus 1fil}{0em plus 1fil}
\begin{document}
\footnote{aśeṣavācyavācakātmakajagadabhedacamatkārātmakaśabdarāśivimarśaparamārthā sar\-vamantrāraṇis tatra tatrāgameṣu nirdiśyate | sā caiṣā viśvāvamarśanena paraṃ jñānaṃ prayacchati.}
\footnote{\makebox[\textwidth-\footmarkwidth][l]{\spaceout{aśeṣavācyavācakātmakajagadabhedacamatkārātmakaśabdarāśivimarśaparamārthā}} sar\-vamantrāraṇis tatra tatrāgameṣu nirdiśyate | sā caiṣā viśvāvamarśanena paraṃ jñānaṃ prayacchati.}
\end{document}
```

[image: two footnotes]

EDIT: [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157435/stripped-ending-utf8-chars-if-set-as-caps) question seems related. Adding the three lines

```
\makeatletter
\sbox0{\ttfamily\global\let\SOUL@tt\ttfamily} 
\makeatother
```

to circumvent `soul`'s choice of a font not containing the necessary diacritical combinations brings me a bit closer to a solution, the `ā` is preserved, but I get a `! Package soul Error: Reconstruction failed.` and the following output containing a small black box:[image: tried changing the font]. Obviously soul tries to hyphenate the long word (which it shouldn't do) and fails to do so.

Comment: Cross-link to related question, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41069/soul-dropping-some-accented-letters-from-the-end-of-words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now found a way to solve it without `soul` (which is not maintained anymore, and not particularly suited to work with unicode(?)). I just had to adapt [this answer to abovementioned question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50518/59023). It is particularly applicable to this case as the line concerned contains only one word, thus no inter-word-spaces, which would otherwise create problems. For reference the working example below:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setlength{\footmarkwidth}{\leftmargin}
\setlength{\footmarksep}{0em}
\footmarkstyle{#1\hfill}

\makeatletter
\def\spreadeven#1{%
\@tfor\next:=#1\do{%
  \next\hfill
 }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\footnote{aśeṣavācyavācakātmakajagadabhedacamatkārātmakaśabdarāśivimarśaparamārthā sar\-vamantrāraṇis tatra tatrāgameṣu nirdiśyate | sā caiṣā viśvāvamarśanena paraṃ jñānaṃ prayacchati.}
\footnote{\makebox[\textwidth-\footmarkwidth][l]{\spreadeven{aśeṣavācyavācakātmakajagadabhedacamatkārātmakaśabdarāśivimarśaparamārthā}} sar\-vamantrāraṇis tatra tatrāgameṣu nirdiśyate | sā caiṣā viśvāvamarśanena paraṃ jñānaṃ prayacchati.}
\end{document}
```

I guess that's good enough a solution. Theoretically it would be nice to also incorporate the `\makebox` command into the `\spreadeven` macro, but the fact that the length of the box can differ makes it difficult.

Answer (score 3):

I can’t explain why `soul` chokes on your text, but since you’re using `fontspec`, perhaps you’re also compiling with `luatex`, and in that case you can play with `chickenize`, which seems to do the trick.

Use it this way:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec,chickenize}
\begin{document}
\letterspaceadjust% letterspace globally to improve greyness
blah blah blah
\end{document}
```

or this way:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec,chickenize}
\begin{document}
blah blah blah

\textletterspaceadjust{Letterspace this sentence to improve its greyness.}
\end{document}
```

EDIT:

Here’s a third way to use `chickenize`.  As muk.li commented, the second introduces an unwanted space at the beginning of the note; as for the first, its global reach may be undesirable.  But using  `\letterspaceadjust` before the text you want to affect and `\unletterspaceadjust` after seems to avoid both problems:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{chickenize,fontspec}

\setlength{\footmarkwidth}{\leftmargin}
\setlength{\footmarksep}{0em}
\footmarkstyle{#1\hfill}

\begin{document}
\letterspaceadjust
\footnote{aśeṣavācyavācakātmakajagadabhedacamatkārātmakaśabdarāśivimarśaparamārthā sar\-vamantrāraṇis tatra tatrāgameṣu nirdiśyate | sā caiṣā viśvāvamarśanena paraṃ jñānaṃ prayacchati.}

\unletterspaceadjust
\footnote{aśeṣavācyavācakātmakajagadabhedacamatkārātmakaśabdarāśivimarśaparamārthā sar\-vamantrāraṇis tatra tatrāgameṣu nirdiśyate | sā caiṣā viśvāvamarśanena paraṃ jñānaṃ prayacchati.}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of MWE]

Comment: I use xelatex. I've tried your second suggestion, giving me the following output: [testing chickenize](http://i.imgur.com/0kx5fJJ.png). Not exactly what I want, but pointing me to a possible, a bit less ugly workaround of adding some empty space at the beginning of the line.

Comment: Or I believe that you can use `\textletterspaceadjust{SomeStuff}` rather than `\unletterspaceadjust`